# Angular ui-grid grouping showing duplicate rows

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, angular-ui-grid

I am new to Angular and trying to group row's using Angular ui.grid.grouping. But I am seeing duplicate rows and its not grouped properly. I am using **Angular js 1.7.2 version**

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.grouping' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridGroupingConstants', function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridGroupingConstants ) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableGrouping:true,
    treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false,
    columnDefs: [


            { name: 'City', width:'50%', grouping: { groupPriority: 0 },defaultSort: {priority: 0}},
            { name: 'CustomerName', width:'30%' }

    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.data = [
                    {    "City": "TEXAS", "CustomerName": "AAA"},
                    {  "City": "TEXAS", "CustomerName": "BBB"},
                    { "City": "TEXAS", "CustomerName": "CCC"  },
                    { "City": "MICHIGAN", "CustomerName": "DDD" },
                    {  "City": "NEW YORK","CustomerName": "EEE"  },
                    {   "City": "MICHIGAN" ,"CustomerName": "FFF"},
                    { "City": "MICHIGAN", "CustomerName": "GGG" },
                    {  "City": "MICHIGAN", "CustomerName": "HHH"  },
                    {   "City": "NEW YORK","CustomerName": "III" }
                ];


}])
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-grouping class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Actual Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

- Instead of 2 Michigan one Michigan
- Instead of 2 New York one New York

Tried same thing using **ng-grid** and I am getting perfect result as below:Exactly same thing I am trying to achieve it using angular ui-grid

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the column order so that the City comes before CustomerName.   Or try setting a sort on the City column

Comment: Changes column order, still same result. What do you mean by setting sorting on city column? enableSorting: true? Tried that, no luck. Am I missing anything?

Comment: { name: 'City', sort: 'asc' }

Comment: @Steve, Tried, not working

Comment: perhaps the gridOptions.enableGrouping is conflicting with the ui-grid-grouping dom attribute causing it to double up.  A plnkr would help

Comment: @steve http://embed.plnkr.co/9AQT2DWdfxu2g0hsfgeK/

Comment: Looks like an existing issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/5495.  Workaround is to either apply a sort to the data before you assign it to the gridOptions.data, or delay a clear/re-group through the api after its been rendered.

gridApi.grouping.clearGrouping();
gridApi.grouping.groupColumn(GroupColumnName);

Comment: @Steve thanks, but where exactly to add ClearGrouping??I couldn't understand that much. Could you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566669/confused-in-choosing-data-grid-with-grouping-sorting-multi-select-filtering-in question, after seeing this I am just thinking to use ui-grid or is there any other free data grid suggestions do you have??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve, thanks for your suggestions. As per your suggestion I added grouping with delay while registeringApi as below:

```
 onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $timeout(function(){
        $scope.gridApi.grouping.clearGrouping();
        $scope.gridApi.grouping.groupColumn('City');
    }, 300);
    }
```

And it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add for column this row, it helps me:

`sort: { priority: 0, direction: 'asc' }`